# tool to generate C++ wrapper over java class

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

From what I understand, SWIG is to wrap C++/C to make it appear in Java, and javah is to implement certain  java functions in C++ ( aka native functions ).
Is there a tool which can create a  C++ wrapper over a java class, so that the caller. of this c++
wrapper doesn't have to worry about java, for example
Input Java is

> ```
>   class hw {  
>     public  void hi() {  
>       System.out.println("Hello World");  
>     }  
>   }
> ```

Tools outputs hw.hh ( and some. c++ files ), which can be used as:

> hw *h = new hw(/*JEnv */ env);
>       h->hi();

Is there a tool available which can do this ?

Comment: Are you expecting this wrapper to host a java virtual machine?  That's non-trivial.

Comment: @Bgen Voigt : From what i read, i think it's lot of boilerplate code .. may be non-trivial, but sth that can be done by tool.  All the existing tools are oriented towards using java as framework, and c++ code as library .. i was trying to do the opposite .. java as libraray, which c++ will call as and when needed.  .. I've a feeling this type of tool can be done using java reflection api !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options include, the following, in ascending order of expense to you.

- Hand-written [JNI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/index.html) code written by clients of your Java class.
- Hand-written, JNI-driven wrappers written by you for clients of your class.
- [JACE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jace/)-generated wrappers. JACE is a free tool. Last version was in 2008; not sure if development is continuing.
- [JunC++ion](http://www.codemesh.com/products/junction/)-generated wrappers. This commercial library produces the best results with the least development effort. It supports Java callbacks, with C++ classes implementing Java interfaces. The author is very responsive and a very nice guy. However, there is a price tag, and you'll want to be sure about deployment costs.

Answer (score 2):

I used this product a long time ago, http://www.codemesh.com/products/junction/

It will do exactly what you want.

Just a disclaimer, I used it almost 6 years ago. I am not affliated with this product.

Comment: . looks the the site is down .. but good to know i'm the only one who has the problem (-: